# Is there anyway to make Hikari plugins with a class and reference the class when loading the plugin?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to discord development but I thought I should give Hikari a try, currently I'm stuck on implementing some extensions and plugins. I would like to put it in a class to work with but I'm not sure that can be done.

This is the code that I've been fiddling around with for a few hours.

```
import hikari
import lightbulb

class Test(lightbulb.Plugin):
    @lightbulb.command(name="ping", description="Sends a ping to the bot")
    async def ping(self, ctx: lightbulb.Context) -> None:
        await ctx.respond(f"Latency: {ctx.bot.heartbeat_latency * 1000:,.0f} ms.")

def load(bot: Bot) -> None:
    bot.add_plugin(Test())
```

Answer (score 0):

As of lightbulb v2 plugins are no longer classes, so you define them in a more functional manner.

Check out the lightbulb [Plugins guide](https://hikari-lightbulb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/plugins.html).